# Note-taking software that uses webdav for synchronization

Tags: note-taking, self-hosted, webdav, nextcloud

Ideally it would do Markdown, but plain text, html, or any other open format would be acceptable.

So far, I've checked out quite a few software products, none of which do this well.

- Sublime Text with the webdavsync package (could not get this to work at all)
- Idees (defunct)
- Omnifocus (not note-taking really)
- Outline (this one ate a bunch of notes during sync)
- Crispy Synced Notes (mostly works, but can't get it to sync to folders on Nextcloud that have special characters in the path)
- Joplin (though ostensibly markdown, it dumps the files into the directory as file soup, not practically readable by other software, author has no intention of changing it)
- Notebooks (no longer does native webdav on Mac)
- Notability (no longer does webdav on desktop)

It's at the point where I've started looking for note-taking software that has a plugins/addons/extensions framework. I've worked through the list of Electron note-taking apps, and none that I noticed do so.

Is there anything out there, even some bleeding edge beta software? I'd be willing to pay (but not subscription) for the right software.

Comment: On which platfoms does the app has to run? And what are your requirements about readability by other programs, a file per note, a single file repository, which format?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul iOS is probably the most important. Mac desktop would be nice. A NC app is almost superfluous if it doesn't hide the files in proprietary formats. If you can tell me that it's my platforms that are the problem and this exists for Windows (or linux), then I might consider that it's my fault and attempt to switch.

Comment: @JohnO - I didn't mean that there are right and wrong platforms, it's just that I'm working on [SilentNotes](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/silentnotes/silentnotes.html) which matches many of your requirements, but supports only Windows and Android.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I'm not emotionally invested. It does look like your software does alot of what I want... and that my hardware's just the wrong hardware. Sucks to be me. Good on you though for having a save featurelist. Also it looks like I tagged the wrong guy in the previous comment. Sorry about that.